# AngularJS Create a filter based on a text field with radio buttons as search sub category

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, radio-button, textfield

I have a search module on a table (filter on all column of the table - one table column corresponds to one field of the JSON property). The search (text field) on the table and sorts on column header of the table are working.

I would like to add radio button under the search text field for improving my search (add filter). Hence the search will be based on the text entered for the field chosen.

My goal: when I enter "char" in the text field, first the system should see all result by default (as it's currently the case). After if I select the radio button "Person", only the results with the person containing "char" should appear. If I click on "description", the radio button "Person" should be unselected and only result with the description containing "char" should appear.

***Here my view:***

```
<div class="spacer input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Search name..." ng-change="search(searchText)"/>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="razRecherche()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>HERE THE RADIO BUTTONS</div>
</div>


<div class="table-responsive" id="allContacts">
    <table ng-show="contacts.length" class="table table-striped table-hover spacer">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="colPerson">
                    <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('PERSON')">Person</a>
                    <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('PERSON')"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="colCompany">
                    <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('COMPANY')">Company</a>
                    <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('COMPANY')"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="colDescription">
                    <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')">Description</a>
                    <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')"></span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>       


        <tbody ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText | orderBy:champTri:triDescendant">
            <tr class="clickable">
                <td class="colPerson" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" ng-class="{sel:selIdx==$index}"><a href="#/view-contacts/{{contact.ID}}">{{contact.PERSON}}</a></td>
                <td class="colCompany" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)">{{contact.COMPANY}}</td>
                <td class="colDescription" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)">{{contact.REQUESTDESCRIPTION}}</td>        
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

***My controller***

```
app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, $timeout, ContactService){

    $scope.search = function(searchText) {
        $scope.reloadPreviousSearch = false;

        if (!searchText.length) {
            //alert("searchText empty");
        }
        if (searchText.length>2) {

            $timeout(function () {
                // RETRIEVE DATA FROM JSON OBJECT OF THE SERVER SEVICE AND A DB QUERY - OK
                ContactService.fastSearch(searchText).success(function(contacts){
                    console.log("query fastSearch OK");                             
                    var length = contacts.length;
                    $scope.loading = false;

                    if (length == 0) {
                        $scope.searchButtonText = "No result";          
                    }else {
                        $scope.searchButtonText = length + " results found";        
                    }
                    // For the orderby date
                    for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
                        if(contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE!=""){
                            contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE = new Date(contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE.replace(/-/g,"/"));
                        }else{
                            contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE=null;
                        }
                    }           

                    $scope.contacts = contacts; 
                    $scope.champTri='PERSON';

                    $scope.selIdx= -1;

                    $scope.selContact=function(contact,idx){
                        $scope.selectedContact=contact;
                        $scope.selIdx=idx;
                        window.location="#/view-contacts/" + idx;
                    }

                    $scope.isSelContact=function(contact){
                        return $scope.selectedContact===contact;
                    }           

                });                                         
            }, 1000);               
        }else{
            $scope.contacts=null;
        }   
    }


    // SEARCH

    $scope.searchText = null;
    $scope.razRecherche = function() {
        $scope.searchText = null;
        $scope.contacts=null;
    }   

    // SORT

    $scope.champTri = null;
    $scope.triDescendant = false;
    $scope.personsSort = function(champ) {
        if ($scope.champTri == champ) {
            $scope.triDescendant = !$scope.triDescendant;
        } else {
            $scope.champTri = champ;
            $scope.triDescendant = false;
        }   
    }

    $scope.cssChevronsTri = function(champ) {
        return {
            glyphicon: $scope.champTri == champ,
            'glyphicon-chevron-up' : $scope.champTri == champ && !$scope.triDescendant,
            'glyphicon-chevron-down' : $scope.champTri == champ && $scope.triDescendant 
        };
    }

});
```

I'm trying to add the radio buttons for filtering the table from the text entered in the text field. But my filter is not working.

Could you please help me to add the filters on the text field (searchText) with the radio button?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do i undersant correctly - you want to show only persons who contains "char" in your     $scope.contacts after checkbox filter?

Comment: Yes the table of results is filtered with the field persons containing "char". If you choose the checkbox "company", the table is filtered with the company containing "char". One search text but one or several additional fllters based on the search text.